# Table stretches out in Google Chrome and Opera webbrowser when I refresh the page

Tags: html, css, html-table, stretched

I made an HTML table,

[image: How a normal table looks like]

But when I refresh my page it's totally stretched out in Google Chrome and in the [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) webbrowser. It's also tested in Internet Explorer and Firefox and there it stays the normal table.

The subnormal table after page refresh looks like:

[image: Subnormal table]

Under this you can see the CSS part of my table:

```
.rdThemeDataTableCell, table.rdAgDataTable td {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
}

td.rdThemeDataTableCell.rdCgPositionCellXAxis {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-style: none;
}

td.rdThemeDataTableCell.rdCgPositionCellXAxis {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Now I don't know how this comes that it works in some browser and in some it doesn't, but it needs to work everywhere.

Comment: That is not enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: do you have experience with this problem?

Comment: If I had, I might have got some HTML that could cause it.

Comment: HTML is auto generated by Logi Info and without css, I don't have the problem, so the cause is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I used a time input, but my time picker didn't have a style class. This created the problem that Chrome and Opera couldn't react well on it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this might help you or not.

The padding, border seems to be varying in different browsers. To the best of my knowledge your problem is related to a specific browser.

There are ways to target a specific browser and apply custom styling to presice content where the problem located.

-[WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)- For Chorme, Opera

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {    
    .ar #form-wrapper {
        width: 330px;
    }      
}
```

moz-document For Firefox:

```
 @-moz-document url-prefix() {       
    .submit_btn {
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
}
```

[Link regarding other browser tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/).